# Div appears despite timeout going

Tags: javascript, css

I am following this tutorial on W3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp

I am trying to increase the time to 10 seconds (10000 ms) but for some reason it fades away after 3ish seconds but then pops up and then dissapears after 7 seconds. Is there a way to fix this?

Code from link:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
  x.className = "show";
  setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 10000);
}
```

```css
#snackbar {
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Snackbar / Toast</h2>
<p>Snackbars are often used as a tooltips/popups to show a message at the bottom of the screen.</p>
<p>Click on the button to show the snackbar. It will disappear after 3 seconds.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>

<div id="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is giving you this error

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you show us your code, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the css. Change the delay like :

```
/* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar.
However, delay the fade out process for 9.5 seconds */

-webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 9.5s;
animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 9.5s;
```

Live example :

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the snackbar DIV
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");

  // Add the "show" class to DIV
  x.className = "show";

  // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
  setTimeout(function() {
    x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
/* The snackbar - position it at the bottom and in the middle of the screen */

#snackbar {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Hidden by default. Visible on click */
  min-width: 250px;
  /* Set a default minimum width */
  margin-left: -125px;
  /* Divide value of min-width by 2 */
  background-color: #333;
  /* Black background color */
  color: #fff;
  /* White text color */
  text-align: center;
  /* Centered text */
  border-radius: 2px;
  /* Rounded borders */
  padding: 16px;
  /* Padding */
  position: fixed;
  /* Sit on top of the screen */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Add a z-index if needed */
  left: 50%;
  /* Center the snackbar */
  bottom: 30px;
  /* 30px from the bottom */
}


/* Show the snackbar when clicking on a button (class added with JavaScript) */

#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible;
  /* Show the snackbar */
  /* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar.
  However, delay the fade out process for 4.5 seconds */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
}


/* Animations to fade the snackbar in and out */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Use a button to open the snackbar -->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar 5sec</button>

<!-- The actual snackbar -->
<div id="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>
```

### Edit

If you want to use a css delay in function of the JS delay you can create multiple css class like :

```css
#snackbar.show3 {
  visibility: visible; /* Show the snackbar */
  /* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar.
  However, delay the fade out process for 2.5 seconds */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

#snackbar.show5 {
  visibility: visible; /* Show the snackbar */
  /* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar.
  However, delay the fade out process for 4.5 seconds */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
}

#snackbar.show10 {
  visibility: visible; /* Show the snackbar */
  /* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar.
  However, delay the fade out process for 4.5 seconds */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 9.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 9.5s;
}
```

And with your JS you can use the desired animation delay

```js
var desiredDelay = 5;

function myFunction() {
  // Get the snackbar DIV
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");

  // Add the "show" class to DIV
  x.className = "show" + desiredDelay;

  // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
  setTimeout(function() {
    x.className = x.className.replace("show" + desiredDelay, "");
  }, (desiredDelay * 1000));
}
```

Comment: Ah Okay, I get it, and would it be possible to use a variable in css? E.g. if i create a function and pass in 5, it should fade for 5 seconds etc?

Comment: @kjvf there is no need of fade out. this answerer have not removed it from css. fadeout is only needed in js.

Comment: @SagarBhamare The fadeOut animation is stardted by the css `animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 9.5s;` see the comment : "*Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar.
However, delay the fade out process for 9.5 seconds*"

Comment: @R3tep the exact problem statement is "Div appears despite timeout going". and settimeout function is a place where it is managing its fadeout. hence css fadeout not needed. Also you are talking about adjusting fadein with 0.5 secs or 500 milliseconds which can be added/adjusted manually with code provided by me above(latest update). thanks

Comment: @SagarBhamare It not managing the fadeOut animation ! but it remove the css class. The fadeOut is only managed by the css on this example. So if you remove the fadeOut into the css, you remove the animation. The element disapear with the JS but without the fadeout animation ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I suppose you changed the `3000` value in JS. As the code goes, you need to change CSS as well.

```
#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible; /* Show the snackbar */
  /* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar. 
  However, delay the fade out process for 9.5 seconds */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 9.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 9.5s;
}
```

The `2.5` will become a `9.5` = 2.5 + 7;

Answer (score 0):

You must change the values in both the css code below to whatever amount of time you want. e.g. If you want 10 seconds change the values below to equal 10.

```
-webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s; // 3 seconds in total
animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s; // 3 seconds in total
```

The total time should equal the timeout function seconds in the script below:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
  x.className = "show";
  setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000); // total time
}
</script>
```

The `3000` above should be `10000` if you want to set the timeout to be 10 seconds in accordance with the css.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the animation timeframe you mentioned

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#snackbar {
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s, fadeout 5s 9s;
  animation: fadein 1s, fadeout 5s 9s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Snackbar / Toast</h2>
<p>Snackbars are often used as a tooltips/popups to show a message at the bottom of the screen.</p>
<p>Click on the button to show the snackbar. It will disappear after 3 seconds.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>

<div id="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
  x.className = "show";
  setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 10000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```